# Scheduling a function in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I am trying to schedule the following function to run every 10seconds. But it tells that it needs a void function. Is there any way to schedule the following function?

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public FtpOutboundGateway getFiles() {
    FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "mget", "payload");
    gateway.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    gateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("./downloads/"));
    gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE_IF_MODIFIED);
    gateway.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    gateway.setOutputChannelName("fileResults");
    return gateway;
}
```

Comment: I believe making this method private, and making a new void method to call it would be better, in the void method you can get the result of this method and throw an exception if the gateway isn't something that you wanted. https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we need to do the following things.

1. First put this Annotation @EnableScheduling at the class level.
2. then at the function which needs to be scheduled should be marked with @Scheduled.
3. The function that we are trying to schedule should not return anything.

```
@EnableScheduling
class <ClassName>{
//def

 @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "10000")
 public void fxnName() {
   //def
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `@Scheduled` method is called internally by the threads in thread pool in a given interval or time, the annotation expect it to be void because it doesn't make sense to return values. if you want to track down the response the extract it to another method and call it from the `@Scheduled` method as well as from other services.